# Setting proxy settings to “Auto Proxy Detection” using the command line in macOS

Tags: macos, bash, proxy

I want to know how to set the proxy settings to “Auto Proxy Detection” like in network preferences, but using the shell.

I have tried looking around but I only am finding commands like:

```
networksetup -gethttpproxy
```

Answer (score 3):

A quick look at the output of `networksetup -help` shows us some promising options:

I'm not sure whether you want "auto detection" or "auto setup", but both ways are provided:

```
networksetup -setproxyautodiscovery <networkservice> <on off>
networksetup -setautoproxyurl <networkservice> <url>
```

The "network service" is the "name" of the connection as shown in the network preferences.

As an example, to enable auto discovery on your Ethernet, you'd run:

```
networksetup -setproxyautodiscovery Ethernet on
```

For future usage, remember the `-help` trick. Most commands you can find provide something along the lines of `--help` or `-help` or `-?` to get further information.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `-setautoproxystate` option in networksetup command to enable disable the 'Automatic Proxy configuration. it will check/uncheck the 'Automatic Proxy configuration' checkbox.
To enable say:

```
networksetup -setautoproxystate <service line Wi-Fi> on
```

To disable it say :

```
networksetup -setautoproxystate <service line Wi-Fi> off
```

this option setautoproxystate does not touch the URL field of this setting so you need to set/get it using setautoproxyurl/getautoproxyurl options.