# Setting HTTPS proxies via the terminal

Tags: macos, proxy, osx-el-capitan

On macOS to set a proxy on a users system via terminal, the way to do this is to SSH into the user, and run the following:

```
sudo networksetup -setwebproxy "<INTERFACE>" <SERVER> <PORT> <ON|OFF>
```

When you run this it does not setup a proxy for both HTTP and HTTPS, it only sets the HTTP proxy. Is there a way I can setup both the HTTP and the HTTPS proxy at the same time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For HTTPS, use `-setsecurewebproxy`, e.g.

```
networksetup -setsecurewebproxy "Wi-Fi" localhost 9595
```

For help, run: `networksetup --help` or `man networksetup`.

Related posts:

- [How do you change HTTPS proxy settings with networksetup?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/308766/21471)
- [How to change proxy setting using Command line in Mac OS?](https://superuser.com/q/316502/87805)

Comment: I just did a `grep` through the help menu and found this, was about to post it. Thank you man!

Answer (score 1):

You can try this as an alternative:

```
export https_proxy=https://proxy.server.com:@aproxy:portnumber
export http_proxy=http://proxy.server.com:@aproxy:portnumber
```

See also: [How to set up a proxy via bash shell?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8666954)

Comment: Yes, but this is for an intercept proxy, not a company wide proxy. I have some people to spy on for a little while and just needed it set on one machine, thank you for all your answers!

Answer (score -1):

For activate https:

```
networksetup -setsecurewebproxystate "Wi-Fi" on
```

For deactive:

```
networksetup -setsecurewebproxystate "Wi-Fi" off
```

For set settings:

```
networksetup -setsecurewebproxy "Wi-Fi" 127.0.0.1 8080
```